# FBSDKGameRequestDialog error with landscape app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch

in my project i call this function: (Facebook SDK for iOS version v4.1.0)

```
FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];
gameRequestContent.message = @"Choi thu nhe, hay lam day";
gameRequestContent.title = @"Monkey Junior";
gameRequestContent.to = friends;
dialog = [FBSDKGameRequestDialog showWithContent:gameRequestContent delegate:(id)self];
```

Image:
[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Our app is in landscape and the Facebook friend invite dialog is in portrait and the buttons Send and Cancel are located outside the screen.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the FB SDK for iOS being tracked [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1575070416094371/).

This issue is seen in iOS 7.x so if it is blocking you then you can maybe at least test your functionality (if feasible) in iOS 8.x till the fix is released.